# Sending data to web form using POST from iPhone app

Tags: php, iphone, ios, get, nsurlconnection

I am trying to send data(a username and password) to an online form from my iPhone app using GET.

This is my source code, but the problem is that no data gets stored in my database.

```
NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"email=%@&password=%@",enterUserName.text,enterPass.text];
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://planetimpressions.com/contacts/imagecomm_register.php"];

NSLog(post);
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

/* when we user https, we need to allow any HTTPS cerificates, so add the one line code,to tell teh NSURLRequest to accept any https certificate, i'm not sure about the security aspects
 */

[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];

NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSString *data=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",data);
```

The source code of the web form is below.

```
if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
$email = $_GET['email'];
$password = $_GET['password'];
$conn = mysql_connect("mysql", "*****", "*****");
if(!$conn)
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("imagecomm_users");
$sql = "INSERT INTO registration(number, email, password) VALUES (null, 
'$email', '$password')";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$conn))
   {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
}
?>
```

I have tested the scripts and they work absolutely fine. I am able to store the username and password into a database using an online form. The only issue I am having is to connect to the online form from the app.

I am not getting any error messages in the console or anything unexpected. Just, nothing happens. I will appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Is there an error? Does that final log show anything unexpected? Does a packet trace on the network show what you expect? Have you debugged the server to see what it's receiving? Do you know the database is hooked up correctly? There's a huge gap between this code and your database, and this code snippet only addresses a tiny bit of it. Please do more research before posting a question like this, or ask how to do that research if you don't know.

Comment: edited the question to reflect the changes you suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used UIWebView to solve the problem.

Code to call UIWebView is -

In the header file declare

```
UIWebView *myWebView
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView ...
```

In the implementation file -

```
[myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLTOCALL]]];
```

and the two methods -

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

and

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ASIHTTP request for request/response with server. Download the ASIHTTP file from here: http://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/tarball/master.
Integrate inside project and add to header as well as define delegate in .h file.
Now you can use this code inside your file.

```
- (void)requestAuth {  
    NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" http://planetimpressions.com/contacts/imagecomm_register.php
    "];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.urlString];
    ASIFormDataRequest  *request = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

    if (!request) {
        NSLog(@"Request prepared");
        return nil;
    }

    [request setPostValue: enterUserName.text forKey:@”email”];

    [request setPostValue: enterPass.text forKey:@"password"];
    [request setTimeOutSeconds:30];

    #if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_4_0
    [request setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];
    #endif

    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(ASIHTTPUploadFailed:)];
    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(ASIHTTPUploadFinished:)];
    [request startAsynchronous];
}

- (void)ASIHTTPUploadFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)theRequest {
    //Parse coming response 
    NSLog(@"%@",[theRequest responseString]);
}

- (void)ASIHTTPUploadFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)theRequest {
    //Parse response if request become failure 
    NSLog(@"%@",[theRequest responseString]);
}
```

Comment: ASIHTTPRequest has been discontinued and you're advised not to use it: http://allseeing-i.com/%5Brequest_release%5D